# Google Sheet API - How to get all sheets name in spreadsheet file?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I use Google Sheet API Version 4.
And i want to get all sheets name what available in that spreadsheet file?
So if you have any way to do it, tell me please. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: What have you started so far? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function GoogleServiceSheets(){
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Sheets');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS);
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    return $service;
}
public function getSheetID_SheetName($spreadsheetID){
    $service = $this->GoogleServiceSheets();
    $sheetNumberCounter = 1;
    $spreadSheetArr = [];
    $worksheetSheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetID)->sheets;
    foreach($worksheetSheets as $sheet){
        $id = $sheet->properties['sheetId'];   
        $name = $sheet->properties['title']; 
        $singleSheetArr = array(
            'id'=>$id,
            'name'=>$name
        );
        $spreadSheetArr[$sheetNumberCounter] = $singleSheetArr; 
        $sheetNumberCounter = $sheetNumberCounter + 1;
    }
    return $spreadSheetArr;
}
```

Comment: worked nicely, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

We can call spreadsheet object to get all information of spreadsheet.

```
   $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
   $spreadsheetId = 'your spredsheetid';
   $sheetInfo = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);
   $allsheet_info = $sheetInfo['sheets'];
   $idCats = array_column($allsheet_info, 'properties');
```

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Google api lets do it.

You need to do api call:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/public/basic?alt=json

Where the "key" is your spreadsheet.

Good luck!